# finding unconditional distribution by integrating conditional distribution

Tags: calculus, probability

Given $$ f_Y (y)= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{120} e^{-\frac{1}{120}y} &, y\ge 0 \\ 0, &, y< 0 \end{cases}$$

and

$$f_{X|Y} (x|y) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{y} &, x\in [0, y] \\0 &, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

how do I find $F_X(100)$?

The hint says that to find the unconditional probability of $X$, one must integrate the the conditional probability of $X$, namely $f_{X|Y} (x|y) $.

However I do not know how to do that exactly. The only solution I could find was to integrate $f_{X,Y} (x,y)$ over $y$... however the problem is that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)= f_Y(y) \cdot f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{1}{120y} e^{-\frac{1}{120}y}$ does not have an elementary derivative and we aren't expected to know anything about exponential integrals.

Is there any other way to find $F_X(x)$? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is correct I guess this link might help you.
http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=499080
Wish I could help more.